# Split results when using multiple variables with label and expression from a column

Tags: powershell, variables, formatting

```
$cluster = Get-ClusterResource -Cluster <server> |
           Select Name,Ownernode, ResourceType, State |
           Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -match 'SQL Server Availability Group'}
$cluster | Out-GridView

$Nodes = Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $Server |
         Select @{n='ClusterName';e={$_.Cluster}}, Name, State 
$Nodes | Out-GridView
```

From the command above, the results are displayed as (depending how many rows).

```
1. Name | Ownernode | ResourceType | State
2. Name | Ownernode | ResourceType | State
3. Name | Ownernode | ResourceType | State
```

Because I am using multiple variables to store results, I have joining columns from both variables into one by:

```
$Res = @()
$Res = foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $cluster = Get-ClusterResource -Cluster <server> |
               Select Name, Ownernode, ResourceType, State |
               Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -match 'SQL Server Availability Group'} 
    $cluster

    $Nodes = Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $Server |
             Select @{n='ClusterName';e={$_.Cluster}}, Name, State 
    $Nodes

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        Name  = $cluster.Name
        Owner = $cluster.Ownernode
        Node1 = $nodes.Name[0]
        Node2 = $nodes.Name[2]
    }
}
$Res | Select Name, Owner, Node1, Node2 | Out-GridView
```

The problem with this is that the returned results are combined into a column instead of separate rows:

```
Name | Owner| Node1 | Node2
1.name,name,name | owner | node1 | node2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are my two cents to your questions: your variable `$cluster` is a collection/list of cluster resources, that's why you get a list of all names when using `$cluster.Name`. i think you want to iterate through that list of resources and for each entry get the nodes. i also changed the PSObject to return one line per resource and node; not two or more nodes.

```
$Res = @()
$Res = foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $clusterResources = Get-ClusterResource -Cluster $server | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -match 'SQL Server Availability Group'} 
    foreach($resource in $clusterResources) {
        $Nodes = Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $resource.Cluster

        foreach($Node in $Nodes) {
            New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                Name  = $Node.Cluster
                Owner = $resource.Ownernode
                Node = $Node.Name
            }
        }
    }
}
$Res | Out-GridView
```